# Where to download Pylons reusable apps

Tags: pylons, code-reuse, reusability

I've learnt some basic in Django.. and there is lots of Django reusable apps available for use.

But how about Pylons? Where to download Pylons reusable apps?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'll bite. There are at least 2 ways I can think of to answer this question.

1: there aren't reusable apps for pylons. In the same sense as what you are thinking for django. I'll assume you mean something like [pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/). in which the clear answer is no as far as you would be concerned.

or

2: in pylons, a request can be routed to any wsgi application, you can do so in your paste config via [url map](http://pythonpaste.org/deploy/#the-config-file)(not a pylons feature but a paste feature), or using the wsgi app [as a controller](http://pylonshq.com/docs/en/0.9.7/wsgi_support/#using-a-wsgi-application-as-a-pylons-0-9-controller) or [within a controller](http://pylonshq.com/docs/en/0.9.7/wsgi_support/#running-a-wsgi-application-from-within-a-controller). So in this sense, [any wsgi application](http://cdn.pylonshq.com/presentations/WSGI%20&%20Pylons.pdf) (pdf) is a reusable app. And of course there's plenty of [wsgi middleware](http://wsgi.org/wsgi/Middleware_and_Utilities) out there to reuse.

But if you are coming from django and expecting to get the same kind of out of the box treatment that you are used to, pylons is going to disappoint you as if you purchased a blowtorch with the expectation that it would get you to the airport. wrong tool for the job.

You may want to look at [turbogears](http://turbogears.org/) which is built on top of pylons and has more out of the box things for you to use.